# How to convert Option<&str> into &str?

Tags: rust

I find `Option` to be somewhat confusing when it comes to lifetime scoping on variables. I've been trying to extract the underlying value from `Some` inside of an `Option` match pattern like so:

```
let filename = match canonicalize(&PathBuf::from(filename)).unwrap().to_str() {
    Some(path) => path,
    _ => "",
};

// Later, I validate the string content 
if filename.is_empty() {
    do_something();
}
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
temporary value dropped while borrowed: borrow later used here
```

The documentation doesn't give much insight on how to persist lifetimes outside of the scope of the call they're initialized in. I have seen examples [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/can-not-understand-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed/23279) and [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-option-t-will-cause-temporary-value-dropped-while-borrowed/25581). Both examples imply either throwing out the value, or converting to an `Option`, neither of which I want. I simply want to get to the underlying `&str` value once the function succeeds.

Comment: I just ran the code in the link you provided and it throws an error. What did you do to make it run?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I messed up with your code, let me explain below in a minute...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with the `Option` itself, but with the temporaries your code creates. Your main line is quite long, so lets dissect it a bit:

```
let temp: PathBuf = conicalize(PathBuf::from(filename)).unwrap();
let filename: &str = temp.to_str();
```

And now you later code that uses `filename` just works. You may be wondering why writing the temporary variable makes a difference. The answer is that temporaries created by the compiler are destroyed at the end of the sentence that contains it.

Note that the `filename` is actually a reference, so it must have an associated lifetime, which is, obviously<sup>1</sup>, that of variable `temp`. That means that `filename` cannot outlive `temp`. But in your code, `temp` is not actually a named variable but a temporary that gets destroyed as soon as the line completes, and `filename` is rendered unusable.

If you read the full compiler error, you'll see a:

> note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value.

which suggest exactly this.

[1]: Obvious if you read the definition of the function of `PathBuf`: `fn to_str<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<&'a str>` (adding the elided lifetime for clarity).

Comment: I'm curious, where is `t2` getting created here?

Comment: @JarredParr: `t2` is actually `temp` from a previous revision of my answer, fixed now. I shouldn't try to write so late at night...